# Story regarding augmented reality filtering things/people (Not Black Mirror)

Tags: story-identification

I'm remembering a story (maybe a short film) with I believe a female protagonist using some instance of augmented reality to mute or filter things and people. The protagonist worked in advertising/media/conglomerate of some sort which was either the source of the tech, or some type of upgrade that added this feature to the tech. There ended up being some type of glitch or morality play involved in the ending that made it a cautionary tale or thriller. The visual I have in my head from reading/watching is along the lines of the newer Jurassic World or Lincoln Child's Utopia in terms the literary realism level.

I've never watched black mirror, and that's the only thing I could find. The story's are also vastly different, this one was very calm and more Asimov. Very elegantly done. There was a similar question asked on SE, but none of the answers fit what I'm thinking of: [Science fiction story with augmented reality glasses hiding reality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84084/science-fiction-story-with-augmented-reality-glasses-hiding-reality)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks mates!

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I have had very little success finding a plot summary, but this does remind me a little of a Pratchett short, `# ifdefDEBUG + "world/enough" + "time"` - sadly my copy of the book it's in is 3,000 miles away.

Comment: Can it be that you read it on reddit? I might know a story that fits the bill perhaps then.